# uses-permission и action - помогите разобраться

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-manifest, android-broadcastreceiver

Как я понимаю ситуацию

1. Есть `uses-permission` - в котором необходимо указать категорию (событий, оборудованию, действию), к которой приложению необходим доступ (разрешение на получение/обработку).
2. Есть `<intent-filter> <action` - в котором для конкретного элемента приложения (activity, service, receiver) указываем значение фильтра, по которому конкретный элемент приложения получит и обработает intent.

И вот вопрос на конкретном примере:
В сервисе в `onCreate` создаю и регистрирую reciver и сервис нормально реагирует на подключение/отключение гарнитуры (сам сервис предварительно запускается другим приложением)

```
myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

но необходима возможность запускать сервис без использования стороннего приложения (подключил гарнитуру, сервис должен запуститься). Для этого регистрирую `action` в манифесте, но не получаю желаемого результата.

```
<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">             
<action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
```

Наверно правильно понимаю, что в данном случае необходимо `uses-permission`, но вот какое у него корректное значение, как где его найти не пойму.

Так выглядит манифест после корректировок по первому ответу

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_HEADSET_PLUG" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.kiril.micvol.SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
        android:process=":service">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.kiril.micvol.MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_HEADSET_PLUG"
        android:process=":service">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.kiril.micvol.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":service">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.kiril.micvol" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ресивер должен быть прописан в манифесте чтобы он мог получать сообщения без нужды в работающем приложении.
2. Чтобы ресивер был зарегистрирован системой для получения уведомлений приложение должно быть однажды запущено.
3. Чтобы после первого запуска приложение продолжало реагировать на сообщения после перезагрузки устройства оно должно запускаться по событию окончания запуска устройства.
4. Для этого оно должно иметь в манифесте ресивер на запуск при загрузке устройства.

**Итого:**

1. Приложение должно ловить событие запуска девайса.
2. Все ресиверы должны быть в манифесте.
3. Приложение должно быть однажды запущено юзером.

Comment: >>Приложение должно быть однажды запущено юзером.   Поясните, однажды запущено каждый раз после перезагрузки устройства или достаточно единственного запуска с момента установки. У меня на текущий момент, после первого запуска после перезагрузки ресивер работает, но после перезагрузки устройства нет.

Comment: В итоге работает после указания обработки запуска в манифесте и ключевой момент, в ресивер в onRecive добавил         `if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) ;
        {
            context.startService(new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.kiril.micvol", "com.example.kiril.micvol.MyService")));
        }`

Comment: @x555xx, достаточно запустить один раз. Если приложение ловит событие загрузки девайса, то юзеру больше ничего делать не надо. Если же он `Force Stop` приложению сделает, то оно не будет работать пока он его заново не запустит.